# Regex match unless string is found

Tags: regex, powershell

Can someone give me a hand in creating a regex string to match the first 3 entries, but omit the one that includes "_Classes".

Sample data set

S-1-5-21-1562028002-2160284861-498729489-2544
S-1-5-21-1562028002-2160284861-498729489-5555
S-1-5-21-1562028002-5623562356-895838383-7777
S-1-5-21-1562028002-5623562356-895838383-7777_Classes

This seems to match everything.  How could it be modified to not match the similar string which includes "_Classes" ?

```
\D\-\d{1}\-\d{1}\-\d{2}\-\d{10}\-\d{10}\-\d{9}\-\d{4}
```

Comment: Add `$` to the end of your regex.

Comment: Why not just use `| Where-Object { $_ -as [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] }` instead of regex ?

Comment: Or if this is going to be in a larger string just put `\b` at the end of your regex there.

Comment: Another way is to use a _negative lookahead_: https://regex101.com/r/4ujHsK/1

Comment: @PM 77-1 for the Win.  Wow I struggled with this a while.  Just add a $, so simple.

Comment: If you literally want everything that doesn’t end with ```_Classes``` you can just do ```| where-object { -not $_.EndsWith(“_Classes”) }``` :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\D-\d{1}-\d{1}-\d{2}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{9}-\d{4}$
```

The `^` and `$` are added to force the string being matched to start and end at exactly those points. Since `_Classes` would cause the string to end further ahead, it will no longer be matched thanks to the `$`.

Comment: $ at the end was the key.  Thank you.  PowerShell didn't like the leading ^ character.  But $ at the end did the trick.

Comment: @user11221802, in a regex context, PowerShell (which delegates to .NET regex functionality) definitely understands `^`. If it doesn't work for you, the implication is that the regex doesn't match at the _start_ of the string, possibly due to leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally not use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and leverage the [`SecurityIdentifier` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier?view=net-6.0) that can successfully parse your strings, the [`-as` Type Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-as-operator) also helps in this operation:

> The `-as` operator tries to convert the input object to the specified .NET type. If it succeeds, it returns the converted object. It if fails, it returns `$null`. It does not return an error.

```bash
@'
S-1-5-21-1562028002-2160284861-498729489-2544
S-1-5-21-1562028002-2160284861-498729489-5555
S-1-5-21-1562028002-5623562356-895838383-7777
S-1-5-21-1562028002-5623562356-895838383-7777_Classes
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -as [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] }
```